# Check if number is within a certain percentage of another number in R

Tags: r

How can I check if 99 is within 10% of the number 100 but not greater dynamically in R?

I'm trying to use the following logic..

```
percent <- 0.1
99 >= (100 * percent) and 99< 100
```

Comment: `99 >= (100 - .1*100) & 99 < 100`?

Comment: `percent <- 0.1; nums = c(89, 90, 110, 111); abs(nums - 100)/100 <= percent`